# How to avoid sending params of fields deleted using JQuery remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In this code I was trying to remove fileds for nested_attributes using ajax `:remote => ture` to avoid reloading
the whole page in browser. Although fileds in `fields_for`  was removed from DOM and association was removed from database, the fields of the nested attributes
still exist in page source and raise `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error when trying to send params to update action of parent model

consider the following code:

_artist_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @artist do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br/>
  <%= f.label :style %>
  <%= f.text_field :style %><br/>

  <%= f.fields_for :songs do |song_builder|%>

    <div id = 'song_<%= song_builder.object.id %>_div'>
      <%= song_builder.label :title %>
      <%= song_builder.text_field :title %><br/>
      <%= song_builder.label :lyrics %>
      <%= song_builder.text_area :lyrics %><br/>

      <%= link_to 'Remove song', delete_song_path(:a_id => @artist.id, :s_id => song_builder.object.id),
    :method => :delete , :remote => true %>

    </div>

  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  delete '/artists/remove_song', :to => 'artists#delete_song', :as => :delete_song
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ArtistsController < ApplicationController

  def edit
    ...
  end

  def update
    @artist =  Artist.find(params[:id])

    if @artist.update(artist_params) #=> error Couldn't find Song with ID=2 for Artist with ID=2
      redirect_to artist_path(@artist)
    else
      flash[:errors] = @artist.errors.full_messages
      render :edit
    end
  end

  ...

  def delete_song
    @song_id = params[s_id]
    aritst = Artist.find(:params[a_id])
    song = artist.songs.find(@song_id)
    song.delete
    respond_to  do |format|
      format.js {render 'delete_song.js.erb'}
    end
  end

end
```

delete_song.js.erb

```
$('#song_<%= @song_id %>_div').remove() ;
```

Error

> Couldn't find Song with ID=2 for Artist with ID=2

how to prevent sending params of removed fields by `$(...).remove()` to update action?

Comment: If user removes them you would need to store state somewhere. If you store it locally you would have to send it with ajax request to load more. Or to store server side would need to make a request with meta data whenever it gets removed and store that per user server side then filter new requests accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution for this error. So according to  charlietfl comment, I tried to store delete status somewhere locally, then rails can  delete association later. So I modified the code as following:

deleting all remote script code including `delete_song.js.erb` file and `delete_song` action and `delete` route. then I allowed marking nested attribute for delete in Artist model file: 
`accepts_nested_attributes_for  :songs, :allow_destroy => true`

then adding delete button in `_artist_form.html.erb` file as following:

```
    <%= button_tag 'x' , :class => 'close_sign',  :type => 'button', :onclick => "$('#song_#{song_builder.object.id}_destroy').val('true'); $('#song_#{song_builder.object.id}_div').hide()" %><br/>
```

and a hidden flied to `fields_for` as below:

```
<%= song_builder.hidden_field :_destroy, :id => "song_#{song_builder.object.id}_destroy" %>
```

and allowing `:songs_nested_attributes => [:title, :lyrics, :_destroy]` in `song_params`

once user remove the song field, it will be hidden and marked for destroy later